# On SQL Server Backup: Msg 3271, Level 16, State 1, Server Line 1 A nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup

I am trying to back up a pretty big database and I keep getting this error:

```
Msg 3271, Level 16, State 1, Server {Server Name}, Line 1 A
nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file "{Backup File Location}:"
112(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 1815). Msg 3013,
Level 16, State 1, Server {Server Name}, Line 1 BACKUP DATABASE is
terminating abnormally.
```

Does anyone happen to know what this is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after many google searches and realizing that there was very little space left on the drive that I was trying to back up to, I found the issue.

Resolution: There is not enough space on the drive to fit the backup.

That seems like something that would be pretty easy to display Microsoft!!

Hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

Well the one more reason for this Error i.e. SQL Server VSS Writer.

When disk volume is backed up via Windows Server; a replica also known as “Volume Shadow Copy Snapshot” is developed for the same volume. Further, it calls upon the associated VSS Writer and if an error is encountered via any of corresponding VSS Writer, it leads to the failure of the backup operation. Here, the error is encountered by the VSS Writer of the SQL Server environment that causes the failure of entire backup process.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when attempting to backup a database with multiple file groups without specifically specifying each file group in the backup statement on SQL Server 2008. As soon as I added a FILEGROUP = N'*FileGroupName*' for each file group it worked.